# If I apply for a PhD in educational psychology in the US, how likely am I to find a job?

Tags: phd, application, job-search

If I start an educational psychology PhD, would my background in English hold me back from securing a job after graduation?

Would they even look at my BA and MA degrees, when they are considering me for a position (let's say an academic position in educational psychology)? Is there anything I may be missing regarding this decision?

Comment: My initial reaction is one of puzzlement at the question itself. If you have a Ph.D. in educational psychology, then surely you're qualified to **teach** pretty much all the undergraduate educational psychology courses that one could take as an undergraduate, and presumably the same regarding Masters level courses in your subfield, and at worst your different BA and MA degrees shouldn't subtract from your already established credentials due to your Ph.D. But I'm in math, which is very hierarchical, and perhaps my thinking doesn't apply to educational psychology.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I'm closer to ed psych than you are, and you are correct, a PhD in ed psych should be qualified to teach any undergrad course, although of course they'll have their areas of specialization just like anyone.

Answer (score 1):

While it is difficult to predict what individual employers might do, in general it is your most recent degree that is relevant. Even leaving out the "ranking" of your university, if you have a doctorate in X you are eligible for positions in X.

But, the job market is tight at the moment and you are trying to project several years into the future. But the early degrees are unlikely to have any negative impact for most purposes.

A well-known advisor is a plus, of course.

It also seems like *not* doing this is your worst option.